# wandb [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] error only thrown in Pycharm using python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, pycharm, wandb

I log the metrics of the training results on the wandb online server. This was working without any problems, till the beginning of this week. Since then i am suddenly unable to connect to the wandb online server and loggin the metrics isn't working anymore. I on Windows 10 using PyCharm with python version 3.8.

The following exception is thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Miniconda3\envs\smartvision\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 696, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "C:\Users\Miniconda3\envs\smartvision\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 964, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Miniconda3\envs\smartvision\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 364, in connect
    conn = self._connect_tls_proxy(hostname, conn)
  File "C:\Users\Miniconda3\envs\smartvision\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 501, in _connect_tls_proxy
    socket = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\Users\Miniconda3\envs\smartvision\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 453, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls)
  File "C:\Users\Miniconda3\envs\smartvision\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 495, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock)
  File "C:\Users\Miniconda3\envs\smartvision\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Users\Miniconda3\envs\smartvision\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\Miniconda3\envs\smartvision\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1131)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Miniconda3\envs\smartvision\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\Miniconda3\envs\smartvision\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\Miniconda3\envs\smartvision\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 574, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.wandb.ai', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /graphql (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1131)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Miniconda3\envs\smartvision\lib\site-packages\wandb\sdk\lib\retry.py", line 102, in __call__
    result = self._call_fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Miniconda3\envs\smartvision\lib\site-packages\wandb\sdk\internal\internal_api.py", line 132, in execute
    return self.client.execute(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Miniconda3\envs\smartvision\lib\site-packages\wandb\vendor\gql-0.2.0\gql\client.py", line 52, in execute
    result = self._get_result(document, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Miniconda3\envs\smartvision\lib\site-packages\wandb\vendor\gql-0.2.0\gql\client.py", line 60, in _get_result
    return self.transport.execute(document, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Miniconda3\envs\smartvision\lib\site-packages\wandb\vendor\gql-0.2.0\gql\transport\requests.py", line 38, in execute
    request = requests.post(self.url, **post_args)
  File "C:\Users\Miniconda3\envs\smartvision\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 117, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Miniconda3\envs\smartvision\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Miniconda3\envs\smartvision\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Miniconda3\envs\smartvision\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Miniconda3\envs\smartvision\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.wandb.ai', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /graphql (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1131)')))
wandb: Network error (SSLError), entering retry loop.
wandb: W&B API key is configured (use `wandb login --relogin` to force relogin)
wandb: Network error (SSLError), entering retry loop.
```

Strange thing is, if i execute the run configuration used in pycharm as a command from it's built in terminal it works fine. Since the same virtual environment is used on the built in terminal i don't understand why this exceptions is thrown if using the run configuration in Pycharm. What am i missing here?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In short: somewhere you have a wrong proxy setting

Comment: Thank you, the problem is solved! I checked the proxy setting of both pycharm and pycharm built-in terminal, they were really different.